# Install Ubuntu on a Macbook Air

Tags: system-installation, macbook

I wanted to install Ubuntu on an external drive to be used in my college study.

It is a MacBook Air Late 2013 with i7, 256 GB hard drive and 8Gb of RAM.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try reading the doc on the official Ubuntu site
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty